# Did I solve this problem correctly? $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{n^2}{n^3+4}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

For the following series:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{n^2}{n^3+4}$

I found $b_n$ to be $b_n=\frac{n^2}{n^3+4} \gt 0$ and then I took the limit of this and found it to be zero.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal well I don't feel like I followed all of the steps required for the alternating series test.  I essentially just took $b_n$ and examined the limit.  Is this nearly equivalent to testing for absolute convergence or can I not conclude my answer is correct if I didn't follow all of the rules for this particular test?

Comment: @inquisitor So the problem is just whether or not this series converges?

Comment: @DavidH I guess I'm just confused because I took the limit of $\frac{1}{n}$ and I know that that is a divergent series, but in this situation is it converging to 0?

Comment: You need to prove that $b_n$ is decreasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prove that $b_n$ is decreasing by using the first derivative test (for the function to be decreasing $f'(x)<0$) and considering the function

$$ f(x)=\frac{x^2}{x^3+4}, \quad x\geq 2 . $$

Answer (score 2):

I propose another way to the result. Let $u_n = \dfrac{(-1)^{n+1} n^2}{n^3+4}$ and $v_n = \dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$.

We already know that the series $\sum v_n$ is convergent (by the alternating test for example). Now, consider the difference $|u_n-v_n|$. We have

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left|u_n - v_n\right| = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \frac{\frac{4}{n}}{1+\frac{4}{n}} \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4}{n^2} <\infty,
$$
a consequence of which is that $\sum u_n = \sum v_n + \sum (u_n - v_n)$ is also convergent because it is a sum of two convergent series.

*Remark.* This method is particularly useful when the alternating test fails.